# How to replace a DOM element with another?

Tags: javascript

If I have a existing elementA on page and I use `document.createElement(...)` to create elementB. elementA and elementB are not the same type of tag (eg. h1 and iframe, i.e. can't use innerHTML), how can I replace elementA with elementB without using jQuery ?

What I've tried (insert new before + remove old):

```
elementA.insertBefore(elementB, elementA.firstChild);
elementA.parentNode.removeChild(elementA)
```

Above doesn't work as elementB is being inserted as a child of elementA and removing elementA after that removes both.

Comment: Use `elementA.parentElement` as a context, and `elementA` instead of `elementA.firstChild`.

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild

Comment: @Teemu Thanks! that seems to do it.

Comment: @Xotic750 I have not, I am a beginner at this, will certainly look at that now. Thanks

Comment: Kudos to Eduen's answer. Still, [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) is one of the most versatile DOM manipulation methods, it is good to learn to use it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`node.replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)

> The Node.replaceChild() method replaces one child node of the
>   specified node with another.
>
> ```
> replacedNode = parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);
> ```
>
> - newChild is the new node to replace oldChild. If it already exists in the DOM, it is first removed.
> - oldChild is the existing child to be replaced.
> - replacedNode is the replaced node. This is the same node as oldChild.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('A')
var h = document.createElement('h1')
h.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Title h1'))
a.replaceChild(h, a.firstChild)
```

```html
<div id="A"><p>Paragraph A</p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to replace a parent element `elementA` with `elementB` so that `elementB` has the first child of `elementA`.

One way of achieving the latter is as follows:

```
// Append `elementB` to `elementA.parentNode` first:
elementA.parentNode.appendChild(elementB)

// Append `elementA.firstchild` to `elementB`:
elementB.parentNode.appendChild(elementA.firstChild)

// Remove `elementA`:
elementA.parentNode.removeChild(elementA)
```